# Views in Drupal6 with taxonomy

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I created a content type with name lecture and also created taxonomy with vocabulary and added terms. and selected content type..

I also added nodes to that content type..

Now my question is i want to create a view which looks like as following link 
[click here](http://www.lds.org/general-conference/sessions/2012/04?lang=eng)

Here Saturday Morning Session, Saturday Afternoon Session, etc are taxonomy terms according to my setup..

Also on Top their is April 2012 here we can select month . i want to do similar like this..

Can you please tell me how to do this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with views? what is the problem exactly?
You are asking for something that is very basic in views.

Comment: No, i am not familar with views properly .. i am able to fetch all fields which i need in views. but how to do  seperate all terms  acc to link given